# List of contacts shows an obsolete name

Tags: category

I want to remove a person from the contacts.
The contact appears in the frontend but not in the contacts component, so I can not remove or unpublish.

(I think someone maybe deleted a non-empty categorie)

How to reset this.

Comment: Please give somewhat more info about your Joomla version (3 or 4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have phpMyAdmin access to your database, then you could remove records from the database. Joomla's default Contact component (com_contact) stores its records in the `#__contact_details` table. Be careful and backup the database before removing anything.

However, if you cannot find the contact that you want to remove then maybe someone added the contact details as plain text somewhere a front-end view. Like in a custom HTML Site module.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all. I found the problem.
Contact was archived, so not visible in the contacts list bu appeared on the contacts page.
I deleted the contact, problem solved.